# Ошибка при установке python-docx

Tags: python, python-2.7

При установке python-docx возникает ошибка

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

С чем это может быть связано и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Пробовал установить на Python 2.7.9 32bit командой `pip install python-docx` - все работает. [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-docx) также указывает, что py2 поддерживается. Какой командой устанавливаете, ОС, версия интерпретатора? Трассировку полностью тоже может пригодится.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: ОС Windows 10. Python 2.7.13. Команда `python -m pip install python-docx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачал архив с пакетом и установил из него. Все заработало